# Как скачать все фото и видео из сообщения в Telegram-чате

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

У меня есть скрипт получающий сообщения с Telegram-чата. После проверяется каждое сообщение на наличие в нем хештега (любого), и, когда хештег найден, то он скачивает фото или видео с данного сообщения. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что когда человек отправляет, например, 10 фото одним сообщением и подписывает его хештегом, то хештег записывается к первому фото, а остальные 9 это уже другие id сообщений и у них уже нет хештега. То есть как получить id всех сообщений, зная ID только первого (с текстом)?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему используя media_group_id